# how make my picturebox cover only my image nt the boarder around it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, picturebox, image, windows-forms-designer

I'm doing a game app in Visual Studio 2010 windows forms, I had inserted an image in the picture box and I need to  bounce my image in the form when it bounces the boarder of the picutre box is overlying on another label or it is distracting another label i.e., it is looking weird as if is is a rectangular image(but i saved the image in .png format)
so is there any one who could help me in this.

and also if possible plz notify me any best technique which is used to make the object jump on to another object(Picture).
(i.e., how to give a best movement to the ball when I press a key) :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you wanted, isn't the image box same size as your picture?
If there is white in your pic that you don't want to show, you should make it transparent with image editor.
Better way of moving that ball would probably be BitBlt function. 
Anyway, it's hard to say what is the best way to move the ball since you did not say how you want to move it. Timer which moves ball while key is pressed is probably the simplest way to do that.